# How to determine row count in SSIS dataset

Tags: ssis, ado

I frequently encounter a situation in SSIS packages where I run a SQL Command to return a set of rows from an ADO connection. There are cases where I want to branch based on the number of rows returned. The ado resultset is stored in an SSIS 'object' datatype. Is there a way in SSIS expression or Script component to get that count of rows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using the Execute Sql task, use a dataflow task like this.

1. Use a source component to retrieve your data
2. Use a rowcount component to store your rowcount into a variable
3. Use a recordset destination component and store that in your original variable (system.object type)

Then return to the control flow and continue as you planned, using the rowcount variable to branch your control flow.

Comment: This was a great answer and a great jump off point into me learning the Data Flow task.  Much appreciated 3 years later!

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Thanks @MattAkers

Answer (score -1):

You can create a precedence Constraint after the Execute SQL Task to the object datatype variable, @[User::objectvariable]>0 as expression in precedence constraint. However in Execute SQL Task you will get resultset to the object variable.

Comment: @Nanda Try testing your answers before posting them, you would have seen the error.