# SSIS Execute SQL Task calls a stored procedure. How to get count of records returned by SP

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2008

My SSIS has Execute SQL Tasks which just calls a stored procedure. How to get count of records returned by the stored procedure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count # of Rows in Stored Procedure Result, then Insert result into table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973909/count-of-rows-in-stored-procedure-result-then-insert-result-into-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stored procedure, you can include a SELECT statement to return the row count.

```
CREATE proc test_proc as
begin
    ....
    select rowcnt= 230
end
```

And as per the `Execute SQL Task` setup, I captured and attached 2 images here below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You also have to add a parameter for the output.